# actual script file name when installed as shell command with setup.py

Tags: python

I'd like to find out the currently running script's file name. Usually via `__file__` or `__main__.__file__` or even with `sys.argv[0]`.

But when installed as shell command with setup.py and `entry_points` / `console_scripts`, `/usr/local/bin/...` is returned instead of the actual file name.

My next guess was the inspect module, like `inspect.stack()[1].filename`. Unfortunately this was inconsistent and did not work in all cases.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: you are getting the whole path right why not take only the base name

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score -1):

Simply pass the full path you have now to `os.path.basename` to get only the filename part.